# How to calculate a sum of sequence e^(-x) with accuracy E=0.0001?

Tags: c++, c, loops, sequence, precision

So I can calculate a sum of sequence without accuracy E.

```
    int t=1, x, k;
    float sum, a, result, factorial=1, E=0.0001;
    for(k=0;k<=(n);k++){
                while(t<=n){
                        factorial*=t;
                        t++;
                }
                sum=(pow(-x,k))/factorial;
                sum+=sum;
                //while(fabs(sum-???)<E){
                //        result=sum;
                //}
    }
```

So I know sum of sequence ***sum(k)***. But to calculate with accurace *E*, I must know sum of previous elements ***sum(k-1)***. How to get sum(k-1) from *for loop*? 
Sorry for english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a remark about the power formula that you apply:  according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function) you should add the terms `pow(-x,k)/(k!)` and not `pow(-x,k)/(n!)`.

This leads to a small optimisation of your code: as `k! = k * (k-1)!`  we can avoid the inner `while` loop and a lot of useless multiplications.

By the way, there is also an error in the way you build the sum:  you always erase the previous result, and then add a second time the current term.

Once this is corrected, you just have to take care of an additional variable:

```
double myexpo(double x, int n=100) {
    int k;
    double sum = 1.0, pvsum, factorial = 1.0, E = 0.0001;
    for (k = 1; k <= (n); k++){  // start with 1
        pvsum = sum;
        factorial *= k;            // don't calculate factorial for 0. 
        sum += (pow(-x, k)) / factorial;

        if (k > 1 && fabs(sum - pvsum) < E) {  // check if diff is small enough
            cout << k << " iterations" << endl; 
            break;     // interupt the for loop if it's precise enough
        }
    }
    return sum;   // at the end of the loop sum is the best approximation
}
```

You can test this function with this:

```
double x; 
do {
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << myexpo(x) << endl; 
    cout << exp(-x) << endl; 
} while (x > 0);
```

***Remark:***  I'd suggest to either use `double` or to use the `f` suffix for the float litterals (e.g. 0.001f), even if it works as is.

Answer (score 2):

is this a taylor series for e ^ (-x) ?  if so you've written it out wrong.  i don't think what you've got will converge.

http://www.efunda.com/math/taylor_series/exponential.cfm

e ^ (-x) is 1 + (-x) + (-x)^2/2! + (-x)^3/3! + ...

```
double calculate_power_of_e(double xx, double accuracy) {
    double sum(1.0);
    double term(1.0);
    for (long kk=1; true; ++kk) {
        term *= (-xx) / kk;
        sum += term;
        if (fabs(term) < accuracy)
            break;
    }

    return sum;
}

printf("e^(-x)" = %.4f\n", calculate_power_of_e(5.0, .0001));
```

Comment: oops.  forgot to update psum.  just put a psum = sum at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Since you have `sum += term`, all you need to check is `fabs(term) < accuracy`. That allows you to get rid of the second `if (0 < kk)`. And if you start `kk` and `sum` at `1`, then you don't need first `if (0 < kk)` either. I fixed it for you, feel free to roll back the edit if desired.

Comment: looks fine, thanks.  taylor series converges slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Check when the absolute value of the term becomes smaller than your desired accuracy.

```
double sum = 0, x = 1, k = 0, E = 0.0001, fact = 1;
while(true){
    double term = pow(-x, k) / fact;
    if(fabs(term) < E)
        break;
    sum += term;
    fact *= (++k);
}
printf("e^(-x) = %.4f", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the term is insignificant compare to 1.0, stop looping.

By using recursion, and `|x|` is not too big, the smallest terms are summed first.

```
e(x) = 1 + x/1! + x*x/2! + x*x*x/3! + ...

double my_exp_term(double x, double term, unsigned n) {
  if (term + 1.0 == 1.0) return term;
  n++;
  return term + my_exp_term(x, term*x/n, n);
}

double my_exp(double x) {
  return 1.0 + my_exp_term(x, x, 1);
}

double y = my_exp(-1);
```

[Exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))